# Flutter: If statement inside a 'Textfield' widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **TextField** widget and a longer **hintText**. Picture below:

[image: TextField with a hintText]

I noticed that when the width of one's screen is smaller than 389 pixels (many smartphones), some of the hintText begins to drop off.

[image: TextField but with some of the hintText missing]

The way I approached this problem is by trying to make the maxLines for the TextField 6 heigh, instead of 5 when the phone's screen is smaller than 389 pixels, to make sure that this all fit. However, it seems that I am unable to add an if/else statement into a TextField widget (unless I am doing something wrong)? Does anyone have any suggestions?

[image: Screenshot of the if/else statement]

```dart
child: TextField(
                              
   if (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 389)
      {maxLines: 6}
   else 
      {maxLines: 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do it:

1. As you want to added condition for maxLines

   `maxLines: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 389 ? 6 : 5`
2. You can use AutoSizeText plugin, which will automatically adjust the size of text based on size. please check [HERE](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text)

Comment: Thank you so much, Akrosh! That is very helpful. Thumbs up to you, good sir